# Bash grep transform vertical to horizontal list

Tags: bash, grep

I'm not getting the result expect from the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html | grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})'
```

this is output:

```
$90.850
$0
$389
$469
$670
$750
$684
$21.744
$604
```

Here is the result I desire, in console.

```
$90.850 $0 $389 $469 $670 $750 $684 $21.744 $604
```

I appreciate your answers. thanks

luis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other solutions:

```
$ echo $(grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html)
$ grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html | xargs echo
$ grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html | tr '\n' ' '
$ grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html | perl -pe 's/\n/ /;'
```

And without `grep`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1 " if /([\$][0-9.]{1,7})/' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix would be to translate the newlines into spaces (I also removed your unnecessary use of `cat`):

```
grep -oiE '([$][0-9.]{1,7})' /home/opmeitle/html/fiesta-one.html | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Beat me to it. There is probably a "cleaner" solution in awk, but I wouldn't be able to write something for that without sample data.